# Trace of an element of a number field is in $\mathbb{Q}$. A strange proof

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I found a proof ([Here, at the beginning](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~malab/PDFs/Algae_are_more_numb_4.pdf)) (it's about the discriminant but still applies for the trace) of the well-known fact that $\text{Tr}_{K|\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}$ which seems to use that if $\beta \in K$ is fixed by all embeddings $K\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Now this should be equivalent to being the extension a Galois extension, but for example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})|\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois, so the proof given cannot work in this case.

The proof I thought for a number field would be to use the fact that given $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, then $$\text{Tr}_{K|\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$

and this should be true for any separable extension $E|F$.

**So** am I right that the linked proof is not working (without adding Galois extension in the hypothesis at least)?

Are there other easy proofs of the fact that the trace in a separable algebraic extension $E|F$ is an element of the base-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you read is fine (although I can't find it in the pdf that's linked in the question).

If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is any field and $C$ is any algebraically closed field whose cardinality is bigger than that of $K$, then an element $\alpha$ of $K$ will be in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if its image under any embedding into $C$ is the same. This is true whether or not $K$ is Galois or even algebraic.

One direction is obvious; for the other, let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (both sides of the equivalence are false if $\alpha$ is transcendental); the coefficients of $f$ are rational numbers so it is unambiguously a polynomial with coefficients in $C$, where it splits. There is an embedding of $K$ into $C$ which sends $\alpha$ to any root of this polynomial. It follows that this polynomial is linear (its roots are distinct as we are in characteristic 0).

Your proof is fine too except that what you are writing down may be a fractional multiple of the trace (if your element belongs to a subfield of the field under consideration). But of course this does not change the result that the trace is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: the proof is in the remark at the beginning

Comment: @luigim the determinant they're talking about is not the same thing as the trace, but again the proof there is fine

Comment: yes, sorry I meant the idea behind it!. Anyway if I'm correct, the key point is that we are embedding in an alg. closure of $K$ and, that's why the notion of Galois extension doesn't come into play. Right?

Comment: And, lastly, can you explain better why with "my" formula, I can obtain a multiple of the trace and not the trace?. The formula of the sum of roots for a polynomial should be that one right?

Comment: @luigim yes i agree 100% with your key point! if the proof had been worded in terms of automorphisms (rather than embeddings into a fixed algebraically closed field) it would have been wrong. With your formula, the issue is "where" you consider your element to live. For example, consider $1 + \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$. Its trace is $4$. But its minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2 - 2 = x^2 - 2x - 1$ and so your formula would give a trace of $2$. The problem is that you're computing the trace from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ down to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @luigim but anyway, this isn't a real problem for your proof. your formula computes the trace of $\alpha$ from $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ down to $\mathbb{Q}$, and the trace down from some general field $K$ containing $\alpha$ is just this number times $[K : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$, so in any event is certainly still a rational number.

Comment: Ok, I think I got what do you mean, have you got some references for this fact (that's enough to multiply for the degree)?

Comment: See the answers and discussion (including the non Galois case) about the question "How to show that the trace maps a Galois extension to the base field" posed by Anfänger two days ago